# Approximating a sequence of tempered distributions "uniformly" by Schwartz functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, approximation-theory, schwartz-distributions

This question has been motivated by the post [making sense of distributions on the diagonal](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459994/making-sense-of-the-limit-lim-limits-x-to-y-tx-y-for-a-tempered-distrib).

Let $T$ be a tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\eta$ be a given [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Definition) on $\mathbb{R}$. For $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, let
\begin{equation}
\eta_{f,\epsilon}(x,y):= \frac{1}{\epsilon}f\Bigl(\frac{x+y}{2}\Bigr) \eta\Bigl(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon}\Bigr)
\end{equation}
and assume that the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} T(\eta_{f,\epsilon})
\end{equation}
exists for all $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.

Then, my issue is

> For any other [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Definition) $\phi$ on $\mathbb{R}$, do we have $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} T(\phi_{f,\epsilon})=\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} T(\eta_{f,\epsilon})$?

For a Schwartz function $F \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ understood as a tempered distribution, a direct computation yields that
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} F(\phi_{f,\epsilon})=\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} F(\eta_{f,\epsilon}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x,x) f(x) dx
\end{equation}

Also, we know that the tempered dsitribution $T$ above can be approximated by Schwartz functions in the weak$^*$ topology. That is, we can find a sequence $F_n$ in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that
\begin{equation}
 F_n(g) \to T(g) \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{equation}
for each $g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Therefore, my issue is reduced to finding a sequence $F_n$ approximating above $T$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} F_n(\eta_{f,\epsilon}) =  \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+}  F_n(\eta_{f,\epsilon})
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} F_n(\phi_{f,\epsilon}) =  \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+}  F_n(\phi_{f,\epsilon})
\end{equation}
at the same time, for each $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.

However, I cannot see how to justify interchange of limits as written above. I guess I need some sort of "uniformity" in approximating $T$ by $F_n$.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first "highlighted issue": **Not** generally. For example, let $T$ be defined by $T\,g = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g\,(s,s)\,{\rm d}s$. Taking $\eta$ with $\eta_1(0)=0$ we get $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}T\,(\eta_{f,\varepsilon}) = 0$ independently of $f$ whereas for $\phi$ with $\phi_1(0) > 0$ and for $f$ with $\int_{\,\mathbb R}f > 0$ we have $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}T\,(\phi_{f,\varepsilon}) = +\infty$. This $T$ actually is the distribution that a theoretical physicist would write "$\delta(x-y)$".

For the problem of restricting a general (tempered) distribution to a submanifold that is not an open subset, you should "take seriously" some comments that are already given to some of your earlier questions, i.e. consider the singular support and wave front sets.

Comment: Well, that is why I said I "assume" the limit to exist. Of course, the limit does NOT exist IN GENEARL..

Comment: In OP you only stated the assumption about $\eta$ saying nothing about existence for $\phi$.

Comment: Well...that is what I am asking... Existence for $\phi$ as well as coincidence with $\eta$.

Comment: To that I have above just answered: **no**. So, what is the purpose of your first comment?

Comment: Is it possible for a mollifier $\eta$ to be $\eta(0)=0$? We have the requirement $\eta_\epsilon(x) \to \delta(x)$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. This is in direct contradiction with $\eta_\epsilon(0)=0$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Certainly it is possible. For example on $\mathbb R$ take any smooth compactly supported $\varphi$ with integral equal to one and support included in $\mathbb R_+$ and define $\varphi_\varepsilon(s)=\varepsilon^{-1}\varphi(\varepsilon^{-1}s)$.

Comment: So you are saying that any compactly supported function with unit integral is a mollifier? I don't think that is the case. You are saying that essentially any smooth compactly supported function with nonzero integral can be made into a mollifier.

Comment: "any compactly supported function with unit integral is a mollifier". Add *smooth* there! *This is precisely the case!* Now you should carefully make some explicit computations before continuing this *extended discussion*!

Comment: Just **compute** and do not argue!

Comment: Your limit above is wrong. Compute it explicitely, noting that in the integral one takes the values of $f$ only near zero. Use the standard $\varepsilon,\delta$-argument, noting that $f$ is continuous at zero.

Comment: Ok, I see that I made a mistake. Sorry about this.